# Passing an operator along with other parameters

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, delegates

I have some VERY inefficient code in which many lines appear 4 times as I go through permutations with "<" and ">" operations and a variety of variables and constants.  It would seem that there is a way to write the function once and pass in the operators along with the necessarily changing values and"ref" variables.  What technique do I have to learn?  "Delegates" have been suggested but I don't see how to use them in this manner.  This is in C# 2.0, VS2005, but if the technique is generic and can be used with C++ too, that would be great.

Request for some code:  The following appears in many guises, with different "<" and ">" signs as well as a mix of "+" and "-" signs:

```
if (move[check].Ypos - move[check].height / 200.0D < LayoutManager.VISIO_HEIGHT - lcac_c.top)
{
  move[check].Ypos = move[check].Ypos + adjust;
.
.
.
```

Comment: Would you be able to post some code?

Comment: I would suggest posting a code snippet on [http://refactormycode.com/](http://refactormycode.com/). Most submissions get two or three alternatives.

Comment: Could someone format that code? Also, could you give us a little more code? Right now it's tough to see what all will vary - Will it always be against `move[check]`, and where does `adjust` come from? Your current guess at a method signature may help.

Comment: Thanks to Rob for cleaning up my code's visibility!
"adjust" is a class variable and I change it depending on the screen resolution and computer I'm demoing the program on.
move is an array of instances of a class
In 2 of the 4 variants of the code I would us Xpos, not YPos.  Also 2 of the 4 have <, 2 have >.  Anything with > would use a + before the adjust variable and vice versa.  Also, one uses lcac_c.top, one uses lcac_c.right, etc.  I would want all of these to be passed in.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C++, use the [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) and [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) functors.  Both of these methods inherit [`std::binary_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function), so your generic function should accept instances of this type.

In .NET, the equivalent to `std::binary_function` is [`Func<T, U, R>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647.aspx).  There are no equivalents to `std::less` and `std::greater`, but it is fairly trivial to create them.  See the following example.

```
static class Functor
{
    static Func<T, T, bool> Greater<T>()
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return delegate(T lhs, T rhs) { return lhs.CompareTo(rhs) > 0; };
    }

    static Func<T, T, bool> Less<T>()
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return delegate(T lhs, T rhs) { return lhs.CompareTo(rhs) < 0; };
    }
}
```

Note, the above code uses the `Func<>` class from .NET 3.5.  If this is not acceptable, consider defining you own delegate.

C++ invocation example:

```
void DoWork(const std::binary_function<int, int, bool>& myOperator,
            int arg1, int arg2)
{
    if (myOperator(arg1, arg2)) { /* perform rest of work */ }
}

void main()
{
    DoWork(std::less<int>(), 100, 200);
    DoWork(std::greater<int>(), 100, 200);
}
```

C# invocation example:

```
void DoWork(Func<int, int, bool> myOperator, int arg1, int arg2)
{
    if (myOperator(arg1, arg2)) { /* perform rest of work */ }
}

void main()
{
    DoWork(Functor.Less<int>(), 100, 200);
    DoWork(Functor.Greater<int>(), 100, 200);
}
```

**EDIT**: I corrected the example of the functor class as applying < or > operators to a generic type doesn't work (in the same manner as it does with C++ templates).

Comment: This is a far better answer than mine.

Comment: In the above C# example, is Functor available in .Net 2.0?  I can't make the above code work?  Do I need to add a reference?

Comment: No, Functor is not a standard .NET class -- you need to write it yourself. Also, .NET 2.0 doesn't contain Func<> (it is in System.Core.dll in .NET 3.5), so you will need to use System.Predicate in its place.

Answer (score 3):

After defining the Enum Operator in the Comparer class

```
     public static class Comparer
{
    public static bool IsTrue<T, U>(T value1, Operator comparisonOperator, U value2)
                where T : U
                where U : IComparable
    {
        switch (comparisonOperator)
        {
            case Operator.GreaterThan:
                return value1.CompareTo(value2) > 0;
            case Operator.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                return value1.CompareTo(value2) >= 0;
            case Operator.LessThan:
                return value1.CompareTo(value2) < 0;
            case Operator.LessThanOrEqual:
                return value1.CompareTo(value2) <= 0;
            case Operator.Equal:
                return value1.CompareTo(value2) == 0;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public enum Operator
    {
        GreaterThan = 1,
        GreaterThanOrEqual = 2,
        LessThan = 3,
        LessThanOrEqual = 4,
        Equal = 5
    }
}
```

You can make a call like this:

```
 if (IsTrue(var1, Operator.GreaterThanOrEqual,  var2))
    Console.WriteLine("var1 is greater than var2");
 else
    Console
        .WriteLine("Unfortunately var1 is not greater than or equal var2. Sorry about that.");
```

---

Comment: Please consider adding some details and explanation to support your answer in order to help others

Answer (score 2):

In C# use delegates for passing the "`<`" and "`>`" operation to the code that's doing the work.

C# Example:

```
public delegate bool BooleanOperatorDelegate(int a, int b)

class OperatorsImplementer {
    public bool OperatorLess(int a, int b) {
         return a < b;
    }
}

class AnotherOperatorsImplementer {
    public bool OperatorLess(int a, int b) {
         return (a + 1) < (b - 1);
    }
}

class OperatorUser {
    int DoSomethingObscene(int a, int b, BooleanOperatorDelegate operator) {
        if (operator(a, b)) {
            return 5;
        }
        else {
            return -5;
        }
    }
}
```

*You should also check that the delegate you get as a paramater is not NULL.*

This is the C method for doing so:

```
bool (*operator_func)(float a, float b)
```

Comment: Idiomatic C++ would actually use function objects and not function pointers (in particular, this would enable the use of `std:less` and other such stock functors).