# Greater in variable

Tags: c#, variables, comparison

Is there a way to say a greater sign **>** into a variable so I can use in say a **for..next** loop?

I have the following:

```
public int findUnused(bool useHighestFirst = true)
{        
    int plInd = 1;
    int stepSize = 1;
    int maxe = maxPlayerCount + 1;
    for (; plInd > maxe; plInd += stepSize)
    {
    // do something
    }
}
```

Depending on useHighestFirst the for loop has to count UP or DOWN.

**How can I put the operator ( < or > ) into a variable?**

Comment: Yes, but the logic is messy. First add some code at the end of your loop that inverts stepSize if maxe or zero is reached. Then in your loop conditional expression, put some logic in the does the comparison one way for a positive stepSize and the opposite way if it's negative

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store an operator in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255618/store-an-operator-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Func<int, int, bool>`, which represents a function that takes 2 `int` parameters and returns a `bool`:

```
Func<int, int, bool> condition = (x, y) => x > y;
// or
Func<int, int, bool> condition = (x, y) => x < y;
```

And then you can do:

```
for (; condition(plInd, maxe); plInd += stepSize)
```

Comment: and don't forget to change the sign of `stepSize` for the countdown version.

Comment: @dlatikay I think the OP handled that already. He probably set it to a negative value beforehand. That is not the question so I didn't include it in my answer. OP would have asked about that if they didn't know how to do it. I think OP is just confused as to how to do the condition part.

Comment: Worked like a treat.
Thanks