# Put bool comparison operator in variable

Tags: c#, boolean

I want to refactor the following code:

```
switch (str)
{
    case "<":
       return value1 < value2;
    case ">":
       return value1 > value2;
    case "<=":
       return value1 <= value2;
    case ">=":
       return value1 >= value2;
    case "==":
       return value1 == value2;
    case "!=":
       return value1 != value2;
}
```

I would like to put boolean comparison operator in variable and then use it only once, something like this:

```
BoolOperator op;

switch (str)
{
    case "<":
       op = BoolOperator.Less;
       break;
    case ">":
       op = BoolOperator.Greater;
       break;
    case "<=":
       op = BoolOperator.LessOrEqual;
       break;
    case ">=":
       op = BoolOperator.GreaterOrEqual;
       break;
    case "==":
       op = BoolOperator.Equal;
       break;
    case "!=":
       op = BoolOperator.NotEqual;
       break;
}

return value1 op value2;
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why? The code above would just be made more complicated to read and slower.

Comment: I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190062/passing-an-operator-along-with-other-parameters

Comment: @DavidG, my original code is much more complicated and supposed solution would simplify it noticeably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use a delegate and some lambdas functions :

```
public static bool Compare<T>(T value1, T value2, string str) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    Func<T, T, bool> op = null;

    switch (str)
    {
        case "<":
            op = (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) < 0;
            break;
        case ">":
            op = (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) > 0;
            break;
        case "<=":
            op = (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) <= 0;
            break;
        case ">=":
            op = (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) >= 0;
            break;
        case "==":
            op = (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) == 0;
            break;
        case "!=":
            op = (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) != 0;
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    return op(value1, value2);
}
```

Comment: Why downvotes ? Even if the original code is ok for me, this solution meets the requirement of the OP.

Comment: It wasn't me, but this will only work with `int` values, what if they are `decimal` for example?

Comment: @DavidG that's right. I've updated the code so it should work with any numeric types.