# C# - Linq - Adding Comparison operators (==,>=,<=,!=) dynamically in linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am working on a scenario and **I wanted to apply Comparison operators (==,>=,<=,!=) dynamically in linq expression**.

example -

**Equal:**

var filterData = data.Where(x => x.Exam.Where(y => y.ExamId **==** examId)).Select(e=>e);

**Greater than or equal:**

var filterData = data.Where(x => x.Exam.Where(y => y.ExamId **>=** examId))
.Select(e=>e);

**Less than or equal:**

var filterData = data.Where(x => x.Exam.Where(y => y.ExamId **<=** examId))
.Select(e=>e)

**Not equal:**

var filterData = data.Where(x => x.Exam.Where(y => y.ExamId **!=** examId)).Select(e=>e);

How can I combine all this logic in single statement (query) instead of writing individual statement(query) for each comparison operator.

User will pass the comparison operator as a parameter and on that basis linq where clause query will be generate in dynamic way....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I suspect a `switch` statement is your initial best bet.

Comment: @mjwills - I am looking for a solution where I dont need to write condition multiple times

Comment: Perhaps you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190062/passing-an-operator-along-with-other-parameters

Comment: Then you have to build the expression from a property, an operator and a variable. There are lots of examples how to do this.

Comment: You really need to add the relevant parts of the classes. Is Data.Exam an object or a List?  etc.

Comment: @henk-holterman - Data.Exam is a list (or you can say array)

Comment: Then you need Selectmany(). Still, add the details.

Answer (score 2):

1. You will need a switch, you can't pass an operatore like `==` directly.

```
string operand = "==";

Func<Exam, bool> filter = operand switch
{
   "==" => ex => ex.ExamId == examId,
   ">=" => ex => ex.ExamId >= examId,
   // etc
   _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
};
```

2. You can't 'chain' .Where statements like you did, you will need SelectMany

```
var filterData = data
    .SelectMany(d => d.Exam)
    .Where(e => filter(e));
```

Comment: then what is the best approach to write this query?                `var filterData = data.Where(x => x.Exam.Where(y => y.ExamId == examId)).Select(e=>e);`

Answer (score 0):

The thing you pass to the Where extension method is a `Func<TSource, bool>` so it's already parametrized. All you need is to create that 4 delegates and let the user choose one of them

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
                    
public class Program
{
    class Exam {public int Id;}
    class MyEntity {public Exam Exam;}
    
    static Dictionary<string, Func<MyEntity, bool>> CreateComparers(int examId) {
        return new Dictionary<string, Func<MyEntity, bool>> {
         {"==", x => x.Exam.Id == examId},
         {">=", x => x.Exam.Id >= examId},
         {"<=", x => x.Exam.Id <= examId},
         {"!=", x => x.Exam.Id != examId}};
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        string key;
        var examId = 2;
        var data = new [] {
            new MyEntity {Exam = new Exam {Id = 0}},
            new MyEntity {Exam = new Exam {Id = 1}},
            new MyEntity {Exam = new Exam {Id = 2}},
            new MyEntity {Exam = new Exam {Id = 3}},
            new MyEntity {Exam = new Exam {Id = 4}},
        };
        var comparers = CreateComparers(examId);
        do { 
            Console.WriteLine("Choose comparison: {0}", string.Join ("  ", comparers.Keys));
            key = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while (!comparers.ContainsKey(key));
   
        var comparer = comparers[key];

        var filterData = data
            .Where(comparer.Invoke)
            .Select(e => e);    
    
        foreach(var e in filterData)
           Console.WriteLine(e.Exam.Id);
   }
```

}